# Numbers with commas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function that accepts a number and performs a mathematical operation on the number.  However, the number I'm passing in could have a comma in it, and from my limited experience with Javascript I am having problems working with that value.  It doesn't seem to treat that as a numeric type.

What's the easiest way to take a parameter with a value of 1,000 and convert it to a numeric 1000?

Comment: @Mike C.-some people go around just attacking questions they dont understand, I don't know why, they just do

Comment: It seems counterproductive to everything.  I wish it would show a log of who downvoted, but I guess that would just breed resentment.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can set up your textbox to have an **onblur()** function so when the user attempts to leave the textbox, you then remove the commas from the value by using the javascript **replace** function

**example**:

```
  function checkNumeric(objName)
  {
    var lstLetters = objName;

    var lstReplace = lstLetters.replace(/\,/g,'');
  }
```

With input tag here:

```
<input type="text" onblur="checkNumeric(this);" name="nocomma" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
```

Comment: I would rather handle this on server side; becuase it could show the user that you manipulated their value

Answer (score 24):

A quick and dirty way is to use the String.replace() method:

```
var rawstring = '1,200,000';
var cleanstring = rawstring.replace(/[^\d\.\-\ ]/g, '');
```

This will set cleanstring to: `1200000`.  Assuming you are using US formatting, then the following conversions will occur:

```
1234 --> 1234
1,234 --> 1234
-1234 --> -1234
-1,234 --> -1234
1234.5 --> 1234.5
1,234.5 --> 1234.5
-1,234.5 --> -1234.5
1xxx234 --> 1234
```

If you are in other locales that invert the '.' and ',', then you'll have to make that change in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

### Updated Answer:

Comma-delimited numbers are [language-specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use) and not all uses this system.

There are many wrong/incomplete answers on Stackoverflow, which are tailored for a specific local, or suggesting a 3rd-party script from NPM, which I believe to be an overkill.

Here's a list of **not-good-at-all** answers:

1. [How do I convert String to Number according to locale (opposite of .toLocaleString)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645163/how-do-i-convert-string-to-number-according-to-locale-opposite-of-tolocalestri)
2. [Is there any JavaScript standard API to parse to number according to locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364947/is-there-any-javascript-standard-api-to-parse-to-number-according-to-locale)

There is one particular **good answer** which addresses multiple locales:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309230/104380

### Previous Answer:

Converts comma delimited number string into a type number (aka *type casting*)

```
+"1,234".split(',').join('') // outputs 1234
```

**Breakdown**:

```
+             - math operation which casts the type of the outcome into type Number
"1,234"       - Our string, which represents a comma delimited number
.split(',')   - split the string into an Array: ["1", "234"], between every "," character
.join('')     - joins the Array back, without any delimiter: "1234"
```

And a simple function would be:

```
function stringToNumber(s){
  return +s.split(',').join('');
}
```

Comment: Nothing about your actual answer - which is great - I just really appreciate the added effort you put into your "Breakdown" section.  I wish more people would do that on here.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just replace all the commas with a blank.

You can follow this:
http://blog.techsaints.com/2007/06/25/javascript-how-to-remove-all-commas-from-a-number/

Comment: I found that article earlier, but I was confused as to where the FormValue item came from.

Comment: with an empty string ("a blank" might be construed as "a space")

Comment: FormNumber should be StartNumber in the link I had mentioned, it appears.