# How to convert a number with comma as string into float number in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im using the parseFloat method to convert a string to a float. it works fine however when the number exceed thousand it one return the value in the thousand place.

So `parseFloat('1,022.55')` 
returns `1` instead of `1022.55`
How do i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
parseFloat('1,022.55'.replace(/,/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is annotated

```
originalNum = '1,022.55';
cleanNum = originalNum.replace(",", "");
float = parseFloat(cleanNum);
console.log(float);
```

Alternatively you can just make it a one-liner by using

```
float = parseFloat('1,022.55'.replace(",", ""));
console.log(float);
```

Comment: This will only replace first comma.