# jQuery extract a call to remove commas to a function,

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract the call to replace commas into a reusable function but I have been unsuccessful.

```
if (Number($amountField.val().replace(/,/g, '')) > 0 || Number($prorationOwedField.val().replace(/,/g, '') > 0)) {
   $taxField.prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. your function is an if statement, that disables what seems to be another field. what do you mean by replace commas

Comment: if the  amountField & prorationOwedfield is greater than 0, the tax field enables.  I am using  .replace(/,/g, '') often in my code and I was wondering if i could extrac it in a function. Hope that is clearer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343179/how-to-convert-a-number-with-comma-as-string-into-float-number-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
  function noCommas(fieldID){
    return Number($(fieldID).val().replace(',', '')) > 0
  }
```

Here is a working fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/sudakatux/3vLnhjs4/11/

Basically you just pass the selector.

You can pass the field if you like

```
 function noCommas($justTheField){
    return Number($justTheField.val().replace(',', '')) > 0
  }
```

and youll use it the same way :

```
if(noCommas($amountField) || noCommas($prorationOwedField))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed!! A small correction for anyone's  future reference, it worked with  a $ sign inside =>  noCommas($justTheField)

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you mean.

You can use a callback.

```js
function execIfFieldsValidate(cb) {
    if (Number($amountField.val().replace(/,/g, '')) > 0 || Number($prorationOwedField.val().replace(/,/g, '') > 0)) {
        cb()
    }
}

// and this is how you can use it.
execIfFieldsValidate(() => {
    console.log("is validated")
})
```

Hope it can help you.