# Getting data from API and converting strings to numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, numbers

I have two problems. First, when fetching data from API I get it only after the interval, which I set. However, first call I need to get immediately.
Second, when I converting received data into numbers, I lose part of numbers, as example instead receiving 11,518.6217 I get only 11.
Can anybody help me, please.

```
    class Currencies extends Component {
      state = {
        inputField: 0,
        exRates: 0,
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        try {
          setInterval(async () => {
            const res = await fetch(
              "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
            );
            const exRates = await res.json();
            console.log(exRates.bpi);
            this.setState({ exRates: exRates.bpi });
          }, 6000);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
      BTCChangeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({ inputField: event.target.value });
      };
      render() {
        const exRates = this.state.exRates;
        const currData = Object.values(exRates).map((value) => value.rate);
        const rates = currData.map(parseFloat);
        console.log(rates);
        return (
          <div>
            <input
              type="number"
              placeholder="Enter BTC value"
              onChange={this.BTCChangeHandler}
            />
            <Currency name="USD" value={this.state.inputField * rates[0]} />
            <Currency name="GPB" value={this.state.inputField * rates[1]} />
            <Currency name="EUR" value={this.state.inputField * rates[2]} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Currencies;
```

Comment: `bpi` entries already contain `rateFloat` which is of type `number` why would you need `parseFloat`?

Comment: Why do you delay render with`setInterval()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a number with comma as string into float number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30343179/how-to-convert-a-number-with-comma-as-string-into-float-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using setInterval, but on first call I need to call it immediately

You should call it manually, as well as calling it on `setInterval`.

```
let dofetch = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
  );
  const exRates = await res.json();
  console.log(exRates.bpi);
  this.setState({ exRates: exRates.bpi });
}
setInterval(dofetch, 6000);
dofetch()
```

> I lose part of numbers, as example instead receiving 11,518.6217 I get only 11

Your string numbers are formatted with `,`, you should remove it before passing them to `parseFloat` function.

```
parseFloat('11,518.6217') // 11
parseFloat('11,518.6217'.split(',').join('')) // 11.518.6217
```

So change:

```
currData.map(parseFloat);
```

to:

```
currData.map(s => parseFloat(s.split(',').join('')));
```

Comment: This is not correct as you now have two decimal seperators in the string.

Comment: Wouldn't `+'11,518.6317'.replace(/,/g, '')` be shorter (and more efficient) way?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov some beginners don't know regx, so it's more readable for them.

Comment: @yaya : I would say, learning new (*appropriate*) tools rather than sticking to old (and inefficient in certain scenarios) ones is what makes them *developers* rather than one-trick-pony

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov but regx is advanced stuff. just look at this question, he is using `setTimeout`, `react`, `.map`, ... without knowing how to debug. i recommend them to learn step by step , not using alot of stuffs (regx, react, es6, ...) while not knowing the basic stuffs (how to debug).

Comment: @RJ No problem. it's better to upvote the helpful answers instead of comment, because when you put a thanks comment like now, the only person who gets the notification is the one who own the answer (me).

Answer (score 0):

This is a locale issue. The Api provides values that have a `,` to indicate thousands and a `.` to indicate decimals. Your client probably uses the opposite. First you will have to convert the string to your clients locale and then you can parse it as a number.

You can either use a library such as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645163/how-do-i-convert-string-to-number-according-to-locale-opposite-of-tolocalestri). Or you can create your own function that switches the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

you can try **setTimOut** instead of **setInterval** then return a promise which fetch the data in api rest

Comment: but the question was another thing. he asked how to get the result immediately, as well as on `setInterval`.