# How to convert a formatted a amount to an integer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to convert an amount to an integer in Javascript. E.g.

`Input 10.555,95
Output 1055595
Input 9.234,77
Output 923477`

I was thinking about removing the dot and the comma, but I don't know if that would be efficient

Comment: what data type is input?

Comment: What about non-European formatted numbers (e.g. `10,555.95`)?

Comment: add replace if you simply want to remove . and , like .replace (",", "")

Comment: @BenM It should convert it to an integer, so it doesn't matter whether it's European formatted or non-European :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use cases, you want to make an integer by replacing the special chars in a string. You need to replace like this

```
 parseInt("9.234,77".replace(",","").replace(".",""))
```

Comment: ...or `"9.234,77".replace(/[^\d]/g,'')` the hell out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wish to remove everything (regardless of formatting), you could replace any non-numeric characters and then force their type:

```
var intValue = + '10.555,95'.replace(/[^\d]/g,''); // == 1055595;
```

Comment: why doesn't this work: `<script>
function ConvertAmount() {
    var x = '10.555,95';
    x.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');
    document.write(x);
}
</script>`

Comment: I don't get any output

Answer (score 0):

```
parseFloat('10.555,95'.replace('.','').replace(',',''));
```

inspired by this answer:
[JavaScript: Parse a string to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/javascript-parse-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: The output if this code doesn't fit the requirements

Comment: It's been edited. It used to substitute comma for dot and then parse it as a float.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I've noticed that it should be always integer after I've submitted the answer. So you could probably use parseInt as well