# JavaScript - Change string to number but keep decimals

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulties with a small math calculation.

I have a string from a form field which I need to convert to a number so I can multiply two fields together (it's a cost and qty field that then sets my total cost line).

The issue I am having is sometimes the number is a solid number (100, 150, 3), sometimes it has commas and sometimes it has decimals.

I have a `.replace` to replace all the commas with nothing to assist with this issue and it works well.

It works great when I `parseInt(var_name)` except it strips off my decimal points. I don't want rounding since it's actually part of a purchasing script.

How would I change my two string fields to a numeric field?

```
var num1 = '100.00';
var num2 = '200,000.51';
alert(num1 X num2); // 20,000,051.00
```

Comment: If you want floating points, why are you using parseInt?

Comment: It would really be helpful if you could supply all of your code, or all of the relevant code in a way that shows the problems you are having. https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Coerce the value using `Number(var_name)`.

Comment: `Number('100.00') * Number('200000.51')`, the unary `+` operator works as well. `+('100.00') * +('200000.51')`. If you want the trailing zeroes, convert it back to a string with `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Parse a string to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/javascript-parse-a-string-to-a-number)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Parsing !== coercion

Comment: if you strip the commas and parseFloat it the math will be correct: `num1 = parseFloat(num1.replace(/,/g,''))`

Comment: @mhodges And...? The OP has a string and wants a number. The linked duplicate provides a number of methods to do so.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So much confusion and misinformation. parsing does not convert a string to a number.. it parses a string for numbers. Telling people to parse when they are really wanting to coerce is just asking for bugs. It's all over the JS community.