# How to check the integer matching and to set an appropriate range in Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, protractor

How I wrote in the title I want to assert exactly integer and later it will be needed to check not specific integer but its range because the number will be changing, but I know the approximate range which I agreed with a team.
Below an example out of which I take the required number to check its correctness.

```
<span _ngcontent-c31="" class="lead-meter__count">
          227,032
</span>
```

But I check it as a string as you see below:

```
records = $('div.lead-meter__info > span.lead-meter__count');
await expect(await targeting_page.records.getText()).toEqual('226,032', 'no no')
```

I want to know is it possible to check it as an integer (though string is being checked very precisely) and further, I want to check for instance:
if this number between 2000 and 3000, it's no matter which number, the main point it matches the range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
var records = await targeting_page.records.getText();
// replace non-number and non-dot to empty string. 
// then multiple 1 to convert string to number.
var recordsNumber = records.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') * 1;
var inRang = recordsNumber >= 2000 && recordsNumber < =3000;

expect(inRang).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your regex approach is incorrect a bit, but the structure is pretty good as for me (not experienced javascript user)

Comment: Thanks your finding, the regex should be `/[^\d.]/g`, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number) on another question helped:

```
parseFloat(yournumber.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

basically, it's removing the commas from the string.

Answer of Yong user below also has come in handy