# JavaScript conversion from String with "," to Int

Tags: javascript

How to convert 1,000 to 1000 using JavaScript.

```js
    console.log(parseInt(1,000));
```

is taking it as 1

Comment: You need to do the following, parseInt("1,000");  The second parameter is the base.  You want to convert the string value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Comment: There are better solution but this would work: `var n = "1,000"; console.log(n.split(",").join(""));`

Answer (score 2):

You should replace the "," and then doo the parseInt

```
parseInt("1,000".replace(/,/g,""));
```

Comment: This wont work for numbers with multiple commas (1,000,000 for example)

Comment: If you use `parseInt("1,000".replace(/,/g,""));` it should replace every comma found in the string.

Comment: You are write, I'm updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to replace all non-digits except for `-` and `.` when passing the argument to `parseInt`:

```js
function parseMyInt(str) {
  return parseInt(str.replace(/[^-\.\d]/g,''));
}

console.log(parseMyInt("1,000"));
console.log(parseMyInt("1,000,000"));
console.log(parseMyInt("1,000.1234"));
console.log(parseMyInt("-1,000"));
```

### Edit

Expanded the regex to account for negative numbers and decimals.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace comma with empty character. Something like this below:

`parseInt("1,000".replace(/,/g, ""))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

var num = parseInt("1,000".replace(/\,/g, ''), 10);

As, we need to remove "comma" from the string.
We also need "10" as radix as the second parameter.

Thanks

Comment: No need to escape the `,` in the regex, also no need for the 10, `parseInt` defaults to using 10 as the radix