# Unformat string with number to number by currency code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want unformat string back into the number
If with USD all works from the box with accounting library, but for example for russian ruble it fails.
String examples are `1,00 руб. (RUB)` and `$20.00 (USD)`
So, I could parse those string and get currency code (in case I might need to provide it to the library) with for example this code:

I tried accounting and numbro libraries

```js
// getting currency code
let init = (data.orderAmount).indexOf('(')
let fin = (data.orderAmount).indexOf(')')
console.log(data.orderAmount).substr(init + 1, fin - init - 1)
```

If I for example pass `1,00 руб. (RUB)` into the accounting.unformat I would get `100` instead of `1`, but for usd example it would work and result would produce `20`. Same result with numbro, only need to also remove part in `()` in that case.

What I really want is solution, where I could pass currency code and string, and get correct number from the string for the given currency.

I tried globalize library `numberParser` and `currencyFormatter` without any success

Comment: You need to parse with different locales since the deliters are different (commas vs period) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: I surely tried `Intl.NumberFormat` first but its for formatting, but not for reverse action. Or I need to use it in some 200 iq way?

Comment: in `1,00 руб. (RUB)` do you want to get 100 or just 1?

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena 1,00 means 1 rouble and no cents. Comma in that locale is decimal separator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````js
function reverseFormatNumber(val,locale){
        var group = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(1111).replace(/1/g, '');
        var decimal = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale).format(1.1).replace(/1/g, '');
        var reversedVal = val.replace(new RegExp('\\' + group, 'g'), '');
        reversedVal = reversedVal.replace(new RegExp('\\' + decimal, 'g'), '.');
        return Number.isNaN(reversedVal)?0:reversedVal;
    }

console.log(reverseFormatNumber('1,00','ru'));```
````

Still would need to cut part from `1,00 руб. (RUB)` string, but shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text_1 = '1,00 руб. (RUB)';
let text_2 = '$20.00 (USD)';

console.log( text_1.match(/\d+(\,|\.)/g)[0].replace(/\,|\./g, '') )
console.log( text_2.match(/\d+(\,|\.)/g)[0].replace(/\,|\./g, '') )
```

Can you try this code? It matches digits until `.` or `,` and replace them.

Comment: Numbers that where provided where an examples, sometime we use up to 8 number precision

Comment: can you give any example?

Comment: `0,00023340` `0.00000193`

Comment: Still, you can get the first digit. Did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your necessity, I could come up with something more elaborate. code to format currency based on your inputted currency

```
const data = [{
  'orderAmount': '1,00 руб. (RUB)'
}, { 
  'orderAmount': '$20.00 (USD)'
}]

const getCurrency = (abbr) => {
  const enumerable = {
    rub: 'ru-RU',
    usd: 'en-US'
  } 
  try {
    return enumerable[abbr.toLowerCase().substr(1,3)]
  } catch {
    throw new Error ('Invalid currency')
  }
}

const getCurrencyCode = (abbr) => abbr.toUpperCase().substr(1,3)

const sanitizeCurrency = (value) => {
  const sanitized = value.replace(',','.').match(/\d+/g).join('.')
  return Number(sanitized);
}


const currency = data.map(item => {
  const newItem = item.orderAmount.split(' ');
  const options = { 
      style: 'currency',
      currency: getCurrencyCode(newItem[newItem.length - 1]),
    };
  const numeralFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat(
    getCurrency(newItem[newItem.length - 1]),
    options
  )

  return numeralFormat.format(sanitizeCurrency(newItem[0]))
})

console.log(currency)
```

in case you want to play with it https://repl.it/@Evandronao/WellmadeMetallicFlashdrives

Comment: also if you want to use only decimal you can change the options something like this:

  const options = { 
    style: 'decimal',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  };