# Use of . and , interchangeable for numbers in typescript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem at hand due to how numbers are written in my native language German. My Problem is that with German as browser language, the browsers behave differently.

```
<input matInput="primary" [formControlName]="question.key"
       [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">
```

I create my forms dynamically.

Now, `question.type` is number.

#### Chrome:

You can put in `,` or `.` the form will save it with a `.`
eg: 11,5 or 11.5 becomes 11.5. The Form also accepts both `,` and `.`

#### Firefox:

In Firefox you can't put in `.` the `type="number"` prevents it. For English browser language its the opposite (as far as I'm aware). You can't put in `,`.

#### Internet Explorer 11:

IE allows both `,` and `.` to be put in, however only the ones with `.` will get recognized as number.

I need all of them to work with `,` and `.`

One extra thing. In my application I want to track these numbers in the URL. Then upon reading those URL params. Which are by default Strings. `Number('11,1')` becomes NaN and `Number(11,1)` becomes 11

Comment: You probably need custom validation as well as custom logic for displaying the numbers based on culture. So you'd need to store the number as the raw value, e.g., `1000.52` and then apply the culture setting for display -> `1 000,52` or `1,000.52` or `1.000,52`.

Comment: Maybe try to avoid the `question.type` attribute and use `text` as your general input type. Then you can probably use the [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) to convert the result into a valid number.

Comment: See this answer for i18n number parsing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000120/1164465