# Javascript counter going to 0 instead of given number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Edited according to voters:

My main problem right now, is that I created a counter in java. Numbers are suppose to go from 0 to the given number at page load, as you can see on example here:   https://codepen.io/corpid/pen/poJERBM…

It works like a charm in that page... in codepen.io,

When I add it to my wordpress site, when I load the web, instead of increasing from 0 to given number (there are 3 different numbers), the counter goes from given number to 0... it goes backwards like a countdown to 0

For example, the first item is supposed to go from 0 to 500, but it goes from 500 to 0.... only on my web, cause in Codepen it works fin...

Webpage to see problem is: https://webreviewing.com/CCMS

this is the function

```
$('.count').each(function (thousands_sep) {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: there's no thousand separator in JS (numerically speaking) you really must use 1500 to represent a thousand and 500 hundred. But, what makes you think that the code should stop before 0, there's nothing saying that

Comment: @CalvinNunes in C# there is `_` as seprator (optional) for litteral numbers

Comment: nice to know, so 1_500 means the same as 1500 ?

Comment: @CalvinNunes exactly. Handy for writing big values in your code. And of course, as user input, there is always the *parse* solution that will use a _locale / culture_ (and now in both C# and alsoJS, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: There is a solution involving locale : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309230/479251

Comment: You have a `foreach` loop going on not a regular `for`. It's gonna loop through all the elements returned by your selector, if any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Comment: I think that the real question here is how she stops the animation counter before 0... I really don't know, it's not clear

Comment: About the "need more focus"  : I casted a vote for closure regarding duplicate with the thouasnd separator, but you have also the question with your countdown, which are two separate questions. (hence, the lack of focus voted by the two other close-voters)

Comment: Here's the jQuery documentation for the method you're using: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Can't you just append `.toLocaleString()` to the `Math.ceil()` call? Is that what you are asking? I'm not sure sorry.

Comment: your problem is that the numbers are counting  and each function overwrites the other so **you don't need to  call** `$('.count').each(function (thousands_sep) {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});`       **FOUR  times    you should   DELETE THREE of this Code duplicates**  , I tested it on your website it works

Comment: for the people who close the question you should stop closing posts unless you sure its duplicate  ,  He has a different   problem   beside the number separators

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan its not closed because of duplication, there are many more reasons to close questions

Comment: i mean i got the proplem solved but he might not see it in comments  i want to add my previous comment as a answer with picture to prove it

Comment: My main problem right now, is that I created a counter in java. Numbers are suppose to go from 0 to the given number at page load, instead of increasing from 0 to given number (there are 3 different numbers), the counter goes from given number to 0... it goes backwards like a countdown to 0

For example, the first item is supposed to go from 0 to 500, but it goes from 500 to 0.... web: https://webreviewing.com/CCMS

Comment: Hi @Yely i noticed you gave up on that animation thing    ,  also  you  changed the class of every number  if you still want the animation  check this , https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/ExjNqYa?editors=1000

Comment: @Yely  you put comma manually remove it  and put the hole number like before inside the class you want  `.count`

Comment: it also added the separation dynamically  after animation ended using callback  i used @Jay Vaghasiya function to do that

Comment: because if the number 1500 changed to 4 digit number  lets'say 20,000  you will have to add it manually  So with this code `jQuery('.millions , .count , .count3 ').each(function () { 
    jQuery(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: jQuery(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'swing',
       complete:function(){jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ','))},
        step: function (now) {
            jQuery(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const numberWithCommas = number => number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');

console.log(numberWithCommas(1500));
```

Comment: It would be nice to add some context to your answer, as it's clear the OP is a beginner.

Comment: @melancia Sorry for that my bad i thought she had mid level knowledge that is why i just provided pseudo code without any description 