# Using Numbers With Commas From Text Input For Multiplication

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to multiply values from two inputs and put the result into another input. The result needs the commas, but in order to multiply in JavaScript I need to remove the commas from inputs 1 and 2. I tried using the replace() method as well prior to this. I have included my HTML and JS below.

HTML

```
<div>
<input id="input1" type="text" />
<input id="input2" type="text" />
<input id="input3" type="text" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("input", "#input1, #input2", function () {
    var val1 = parseFloat($("#input1").val());
    var val2 = parseFloat($("#input2").val());
    var total = val1 * val2;
    $("#input3").val(total).trigger("input");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, convert string value in **input1** and **input2** to float num by removing the commas from it.

Second, do the math as you want.

Third, convert the results back to string then format it with the commas.

**Refer:**

Remove the commas from a string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11665949/11392920

Format a number with commas as thousands separators: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/11392920

```js
$(document).on("input", "#input1, #input2", function() {
  var val1 = parseFloat($("#input1").val().replace(/,/g, ''));
  var val2 = parseFloat($("#input2").val().replace(/,/g, ''));
  var total = val1 * val2;
  total = total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  $("#input3").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="input1" type="text" />
  <input id="input2" type="text" />
  <input id="input3" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is to convert the output to a string and add commas periodically. Here is a code example (where num is the number to display):

```
var str = num + "";
var output = "";

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    output += str[i];
    if ((str.length - i - 1) % 3 == 0 && i < str.length - 1)
        output += ",";
}
```