# How to revert comma format value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I formatted number with JavaScript toLocaleString('en') and now i want to revert the value without comma.
Is there any function in JavaScript.

Example

```js
var amount = parseInt(5000).toLocaleString('en');
console.log("amount:", amount);
```

**result:**

> '5,000'

how to revert **'5,000' into '5000'** using JavaScript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `,` from the string using `replaceAll()` method.

```js
var amount = parseInt(500000000).toLocaleString('en');
console.log(amount);


// Reverting ,
amount = amount.replaceAll(',', '');
console.log(amount);
```

Comment: if value has 2 comma's Example (5,000,000)

Answer (score 1):

I think would be better to keep two separate variables, one for calculation purpose and one for visualization purpose:

```js
var amount = parseInt(5000)

var amountPrint = amount.toLocaleString('en');
console.log("amount for view:", amountPrint);
console.log("amount:", amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = parseInt(5000).toLocaleString('en').replace(",", "");
```