# str.match - how to remove $ and show digital value only?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code
value = str.match(/$(\d+)/);

For example 1: HK$999
Display Result = 999

For example 2: HK$1,999.20
Display result = 1 (I would not want this result)

How can show the example 2 = 1999

Thank you all ^_^

Comment: try regex from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003683/how-can-i-extract-a-number-from-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This code should work fine
first remove all the unnecessary comas from the string
then select all the numbers before "."

```
var ragex = /(\d+)/g;

let str = "HR999";
str = "HK$1,999.20"
str = str.replace(/(,)/, '')

let res = str.match(ragex)[0];
```

the result will be at first index in the array

if you want numbers including.

use this ragex

```
var ragex = /\d+.\d+/g;
```

Comment: Numbers with locale separator can be more complicated than just removing commas. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000120/10317684](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42000120/10317684)