# How to format to 2 decimal places using commas

Tags: typescript

I have the below code in TypeScript that converts string to 2 decimal places:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
    .format(Number(value));
```

It works fine for the following input:

1 --> 1,00
12 --> 12,00

But I also want it to convert 12,5 to 12,50.

When I input 12,5 - because of the existing comma, it returns NaN. One possible solution is to replace the commas with a dot as per below:

```
const formattedValue: string = value.replace(',', '.');
```

But I do not want this approach. I was wondering if there is a specific method, to convert string to 2 decimal places using commas?

Also important, it should keep the original 2 decimal places and no rounding.

Comment: `value = value.replace(',', '.');`, then run your `Intl.NumberFormat` code...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the replacement not after you formatted it, but before you parse `value` to a number.

```js
const format = (value) => new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
    .format(Number(value.replace(",",".")));


console.log(format("1"))
console.log(format("12,5"))
```