# NaN (not a number) when attempting output 2 decimal place for money value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I ma having an issue converting my numbers into decimal places. I am trying to return each balance value which is an actual money value. Here is an example html:

```
<div class="balance-amount">£25.00</div>
<div class="balance-amount">£15.00</div>
<div class="balance-amount">£43,022.00</div>
<div class="balance-amount">£0.00</div>
<div class="balance-amount">£32,232.00</div>
```

So I write a method which iterates through each selector and I output the values in a console log. I noticed that the large figures don't return the number but NaN.

```
balanceAmount 25.00
balanceAmount 15.00
balanceAmount NaN
balanceAmount 0.00
balanceAmount NaN
```

Method:

```
this.balanceAmount = Selector('.balance-amount');

  ...

  async getBalance() {
    for (let i = 0; i < (await this.balanceAmount.count); i++) {
      let balance = Number(
        (await this.balanceAmount.nth(i).textContent).replace('£', '')
      );

      console.log('balanceAmount', balance.toFixed(2));
    }
  }
```

How can I get the numbers displayed correctly and avoid this NaN issue?

Comment: It seems to be related to commas. Have you tried to `.replace(',', '')` ?

Comment: @Tom this doesn't quite work for for numbers above 1,000,000 (use either `replaceAll` or regular expressions)

Comment: Thanks both of you, it was the commas

Comment: and [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Comment: Consider using [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) to help deal with different locales.