# Unformatting EU and US numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, format, numbers

Hey I am trying to write some code to handle the unformatting of EU and US numbers but I can not get a perfect solution.

For example I would like

1.222.222,89 to be 1222222.89
1,222,222.89 to be 1222222.89

I am using AG GRID and I am pasting numbers to the grid which ag grid is storing as strings.

what I have got so far but will not work with numbers with only a single ',' or '.'

let unformattedNumber = params.value as string;

```
unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace("%", "");
unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace(/ /g, "");

const lastCommaIndex = unformattedNumber.lastIndexOf(",");
const lastPeriodIndex = unformattedNumber.lastIndexOf(".");

if (lastCommaIndex > lastPeriodIndex) {
  unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace(/\./g, "");
  unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace(",", ".");
} else if (lastPeriodIndex > lastCommaIndex) {
  unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace(/,/g, "");
}

return parseFloat(unformattedNumber);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a string with a comma thousand separator to a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665884/how-can-i-parse-a-string-with-a-comma-thousand-separator-to-a-number)

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45309230/989920)

Comment: I do not think this works. I am dealing with strings and we are a big company so the idea is that people will share excels with each other and use our app and copy and paste stuff into the grid so they very likely could be looking at a format not in their locale.

Comment: That answer still shows how to convert the string into a number

Comment: So use one of the other 21 answers...

Comment: @eamohego is it safe to assume that all the numbers will be rounded to just two decimal places?

Comment: no so this is used in copy and paste to ag grid. so a user might copy a number like 23.3333 to the grid.

Comment: This can be tricky if the user doesn't define the format they are using, cause 1,567 can mean 1 with 3 decimal places of '567', and can also mean one-thousand five-hundred and sixty-seven. So the program might not work to full expectation everytime

Comment: yeah I can get a solution to like 80 percent work but can't find a perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are on the right track. You can try this out:

```
function unformatNumber(input: string): number {
  // Step 1: Remove percentage sign '%' and spaces
  let unformattedNumber = input.replace("%", "").replace(/ /g, "");

  // Step 2: Use regex to replace EU/US formats with a consistent format
  unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace(/[,.](?=\d{3})/g, "");
  unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.replace(",", ".");

  return parseFloat(unformattedNumber);
}

// Test cases
console.log(unformatNumber("1.222.222,89")); // Output: 1222222.89
console.log(unformatNumber("1,222,222.89")); // Output: 1222222.89
console.log(unformatNumber("1,222,222"));    // Output: 1222222
console.log(unformatNumber("1.222.222"));    // Output: 1222222
console.log(unformatNumber("12% 34,56"));    // Output: 1234.56
```

Comment: no so 123,456 gets turned into 123.0 with this

Comment: In your Regex you should replace `[0-9]{2}$/` with `[0-9]{1,}$/` to allow for any amount of decimal points. At that point, it will fix the issue of entering `123,456` (as it had more numbers in the decimals places than expected by the regex)

Comment: I did that but 123,456 still gets inputted as 123.5

Comment: @eamohego I have added updated code. Please Let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works how You want it to be! Used JS a long time ago.

```js
function unformatNumber(number) {

  let unformattedNumber = number.replace(/[,]/g, '');
  let lastCommaIndex = number.lastIndexOf(',');
  let amount = number.match(/,/g);
    
  unformattedNumber = unformattedNumber.slice(0, lastCommaIndex- 
  amount.length+1) + '.' + unformattedNumber.slice(lastCommaIndex- 
  amount.length+1, unformattedNumber.length)
 
  return unformattedNumber;
}

let uNumber = "1,222,222,89"; //OUTPUT 1222222.89
console.log(unformatNumber(uNumber));
```

Comment: this doesnt work with EU format

Comment: Yes, but works for US so? You can change the code if You have a part of it. It is the same

Comment: So you output one version, the US centric version, and call it a day? As if the EU's style is invalid or something? What if you don't know which version you are going to get?

Comment: It's just a part of code? It's really simple logic If You have one part you should easly make the second one. If else logic is one of the simplest thing I guess

Comment: Okay, but that's not being helpful here? "Here half of the answer, any developer should be able to figure out the other half" is not a great attitude for a site where people come to learn from others?

Comment: I did not mean it like that. He should do it himself to learn, cause those are the things that teach You the most.

Comment: Let him try that individually and then if he have some problems ask them

Comment: 'if you have one part you should easly make the second one' - so show me :( haha I have been embarrassingly at this all day

the problem is edge cases of 1,234 and 1.22 from what I can tell it is difficult to perfectly prepare a function that can handle not knowing which format is coming at it

Comment: describe me perfectly what is Your bigest problem here and show me the examples that breakes the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with regex so I used arrays. May not be the best practice, but it works:

```
function formatNumber(unformattedNumber) {
  const rawNumber = unformattedNumber.split("").filter((char) => {
    return char !== "," && char !== "."
  })
  if (rawNumber.length !== 9) {
    console.log("Wrong number format")
  } else {
    const a = rawNumber.pop()
    const b = rawNumber.pop()
    const formattedNumber = [...rawNumber, ".", a, b].join("")
    console.log(formattedNumber)
  }
}

formatNumber("1.222.222,89")
```

I tried shortening the `.pop()` process by just using `splice()` but for some reason, it wasn't working too well on JSFiddle, here's the code for that if you want it tho:

```
function formatNumber(unformattedNumber) {
  const rawNumber = unformattedNumber.split("").filter((char) => {
    return char !== "," && char !== "."
  })
  if (rawNumber.length !== 9) {
    console.log("Wrong number format")
  } else {
    const formattedNumber = rawNumber.splice(7, 0, ".").join("")
    console.log(formattedNumber)
  }
}

formatNumber("1.222.222,89")
```

Comment: Looks like it wouldn't work on, say, "2,222.34"...

Comment: Oh my bad @Heretic Monkey, I just felt it was just 9 digit numbers. I'll try to fix that now