# javascript - string numbers - convert from 123,456 to 123456

Tags: javascript

I have an array of string numbers like the follow:
"123,556","552,255,242","2,601","242","2","4"
and I would like to convert them to int numbers but the numbers with the "," I would like to convert from "123,556" to "123556" first.
How do I do so ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832829/numbers-with-commas-in-javascript). Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var numbersArray = ["153,32","32,453,23","45,21"];
for (var i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
    numbersArray[i] = parseInt(numbersArray[i].replace(',',''));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "552,255,242";
var numbr = parseInt(str.replace(/\,/g,''), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) (or [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)) to remove the `,` and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) afterwards:

```
var number = "123,456";
number = number.split(',').join('');
number = parseInt(number, 10);
```

Comment: If you don't pass a parameter to `.join()` it's the same as passing `','` as argument, i.e. the comma is the default separator. Pass an empty string, otherwise you are not modifying the string at all.

Comment: thanks for the hint felix, thats what i actually wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.replace` method.

```
"123,556".replace(/,/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `string.replace(',', '');`

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
var parseMe(myarray) {
  var out = new Array(myarray.length);
  for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++){
      var tokens[] = myarray[i].split(",");
      var s = tokens[0] + tokens[1];
      out.push(parseInt(s));
  }
  return out;
}
```