# Is there any JavaScript standard API to parse to number according to locale?

Tags: javascript, parsing, numbers, locale

For formatting a number according to locale, there is a standard JavaScript API: [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

But for the reverse action, parsing a string to a number I cannot find any standard API supporting locales:

- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) does not support any locale arguments.
- [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) and [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) don't support any locale arguments either.

Is there really no JavaScript standard API to parse a string to a number according to a locale?

And if not: are there any market established, open source libraries to do so?

Comment: afaik, no. what else beside converting a comma decimal point to a period would need done?

Comment: Not standard, but you might look at https://github.com/Brightspace/intl

Comment: @dandavis Group separator, e.g. Maybe other things, I don't know because I don't know every locale on earth. That's why I'd like to have a standardized and properly maintained localization functionality.

Comment: well JS has never been able to parse grouped digits or leading char like `$`, which is why i asked...

Comment: See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25645163/8583692).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The NPM package [`d2l-intl`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d2l-intl) provides a locale-sensitive parser. It has since been superseded by [@brightspace-ui/intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@brightspace-ui/intl) (essentially version 3), so some info below might or might not apply in its newer incantation.

```
const { NumberFormat, NumberParse } = require('d2l-intl');
const formatter = new NumberFormat('es');
const parser = new NumberParse('es');
const number = 1234.5;
console.log(formatter.format(number));                 // 1.234,5
console.log(parser.parse(formatter.format(1234.5)));   // 1234.5
```

Unfortunately, that library only comes with support for a [handful of locales](https://github.com/Brightspace/intl/tree/master/src/locale-data) out of the box. It also uses `parseInt` which only supports Western Arabic numerals, so for locales that use different numeral systems, you're going to have to get more clever. [Here's one solution](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/localized-number-parsing) I found by [Mike Bostock](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/). I don't want to take credit for it, but I've reproduced it here for posterity (with some slight tweaks based on my own preferences):

```js
class NumberParser {
  constructor(locale) {
    const format = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale);
    const parts = format.formatToParts(12345.6);
    const numerals = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => format.format(i));
    const index = new Map(numerals.map((d, i) => [d, i]));
    this._group = new RegExp(`[${parts.find(d => d.type === "group").value}]`, "g");
    this._decimal = new RegExp(`[${parts.find(d => d.type === "decimal").value}]`);
    this._numeral = new RegExp(`[${numerals.join("")}]`, "g");
    this._index = d => index.get(d);
  }
  parse(string) {
    return (string = string.trim()
      .replace(this._group, "")
      .replace(this._decimal, ".")
      .replace(this._numeral, this._index)) ? +string : NaN;
  }
}

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('ar-EG');
const parser = new NumberParser('ar-EG');
console.log(formatter.format(1234.5));               // ١٬٢٣٤٫٥
console.log(parser.parse(formatter.format(1234.5))); // 1234.5
```

Comment: d2l-intl's support of locales is very sparsely, indeed; there is even no de locale.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet It seems like the newer versions rely a lot more on the browser includes? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@brightspace-ui/intl

Comment: In order to deal correctly with negative numbers, we need to use negative number in `format.formatToParts(-12345.6)`, store the minus sign (that might be a different char than the regular `-`), and replace it later with regular minus sign. Working [slightly extended example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352853/1761692)

Answer (score 3):

"A JavaScript library for internationalization and localization that leverage the official Unicode CLDR JSON data. The library works both for the browser and as a Node.js module."

https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize

Answer (score 1):

Try [Mike Bostock's coercion of the `Intl.NumberFormat` tool into a parser](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/localized-number-parsing).

```
class NumberParser {
  constructor(locale) {
    const parts = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale).formatToParts(12345.6);
    const numerals = [...new Intl.NumberFormat(locale, {useGrouping: false}).format(9876543210)].reverse();
    const index = new Map(numerals.map((d, i) => [d, i]));
    this._group = new RegExp(`[${parts.find(d => d.type === "group").value}]`, "g");
    this._decimal = new RegExp(`[${parts.find(d => d.type === "decimal").value}]`);
    this._numeral = new RegExp(`[${numerals.join("")}]`, "g");
    this._index = d => index.get(d);
  }
  parse(string) {
    return (string = string.trim()
      .replace(this._group, "")
      .replace(this._decimal, ".")
      .replace(this._numeral, this._index)) ? +string : NaN;
  }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer includes Mike's solution and precedes this one by two years.

Answer (score 0):

This library tries to handle all locales. It retrieves string which contains a number and it tries to "guess" which culture is the number from and converts it to number.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-parsing

Use it in a following way:

```
var parser = require("number-parsing");
var a = parser("123'123.99USD"); // will return 123123.99
var b = parser("1234"); // will return 1234
var c = parser("123 123,777") // will return 123123.777
// and so on
```

Comment: I don't know about it, there is very few download, no development in years (last published 3 years ago), no activity on issues or prs. I would have a hard time trusting that it's solid after a first look :(

Comment: @Elley ... up to you. Low number of downloads is not an indicator of a poor library, also number parsing is a topic which if you implement well you don't need to do any more changes in it. I've been using this library in my projects and does the job well - I would not recommend it here otherwise.

Comment: Indeed it's not, what I meant is that, something great, with not a lot of actives users meant it hasn't been tested that much in real life. If it's used by a lot of people everyday, they test it in real life a lot. So it just a matter of building up confidence into the lib, you see what I mean now ?
Also if it's old, there might be language update that break stuff.

In the end I dealt with my situation without needing this parsing, but thanks for the recommendation anyway :) (I authored a very small low download lib, so I do hope my lib quality isn't tight with my low number of users haha)