# jQuery string to number get rounded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a list with prices inside and I want to get these (in this example one) to use them later for a calculation.

My idea was to get it as a string, convert it to a decimal and then do my calculation with it. The other idea would be to get the string and remove the `&nbsp;` and the `€` but I think the conversion into a number is better, isn't it?

```js
 paidNettoWithShipping = parseFloat($('.aggregation--list .entry--totalnet .entry--value').text()).toFixed(2);

 console.log(paidNettoWithShipping);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aggregation--list">
  <div class="entry--totalnet">
    <div class="entry--value">21,01&nbsp;€</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is, that my numbers gets rounded to `21.00` instead of the correct `21.01` is this because of the `,` instead of `.` in my html? Thats how we write currency in europe, so I won't change that.

How do I get my correct number to use it later in some calculations?

That's what I see in the console.
[image: My Result]

Comment: So replace the comma with a dot in that string value then, before you try to parse it as a float.

Comment: @jabaa For me it's 21.00 I've added an img of my console.

Comment: What's wrong with the `.replace` approach described in the first comment?

Comment: @jabaa Nothing I guess. I will try it, but is that the finest way of doing this?

Comment: Using the replace method.

Comment: [Is there any JavaScript standard API to parse to number according to locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364947/is-there-any-javascript-standard-api-to-parse-to-number-according-to-locale)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @CBroe, by using replace() you can achieve it:

```js
 paidNettoWithShipping = parseFloat($('.aggregation--list .entry--totalnet .entry--value').text().replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2);

 console.log(paidNettoWithShipping);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aggregation--list">
  <div class="entry--totalnet">
    <div class="entry--value">21,01&nbsp;€</div>
  </div>
</div>
```