# Adding currency with dynamic language

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function to add 2 currency with string format and dynamic by language code. something like this

```
function addCurrecy(c1, c2, lang) {
  /* */
  return c
}

console.log(addCurrecy('3.319,00 €', '100,00 €', 'de-DE')) // '3.419,00 €'
console.log(addCurrecy('CHF 1’719.90', 'CHF 100.00', 'de-CH')) // 'CHF 1’819.90'
```

The [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) can help me format the number, but I get stuck at plus number. Any suggestion guys?

Comment: @jsN00b it is ISO Language Code and used as param in `Intl.NumberFormat()`. You can check list of lang here http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm

Comment: What is needed here is a way to reverse the Intl.NumberFormat in order to obtain the actual numbers, then perform the addition and again use Intl.NumberFormat to reformat it to currency. There are other answers that help with this. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55364947/13658816), and [may be this too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29255843/13658816).