# Intl.NumberFormat with Swedish locale and negative value returns wrong minus character

Tags: javascript, internationalization, number-formatting

I'm having an issue with `Intl.NumberFormat` using a Swedish locale. If you run:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-uk', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,
   maximumFractionDigits: 2,
}).format(-2);
```

It returns `-2.00` with minus sign `U+002D`, but if you run:

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('sv-se', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,
   maximumFractionDigits: 2,
}).format(-2);
```

It returns `−2,00` with minus sign `U+2212`.

This messes up my validation functions because JS cannot do math operations with the `U+2212` sign.

```
10 − 2
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Is there a way to set the minus character for `Intl.NumberFormat`? Or is there a way around this without some ugly hack? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use `Intl` to generate JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55366435/1761692) and the original work of [Mike Bostock](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/localized-number-parsing), you can parse locale numbers, unfortunately seems that it isn't part of the current `Intl` API.

I extended the method suggested to deal correctly with negative numbers as well.

```js
class NumberParser {
    constructor(locale) {
        const format = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale);
        const parts = format.formatToParts(-12345.6);
        const numerals = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => format.format(i));
        const index = new Map(numerals.map((d, i) => [d, i]));
        this._minusSign = parts[0].value;
        this._group = new RegExp(`[${parts.find(d => d.type === "group").value}]`, "g");
        this._decimal = new RegExp(`[${parts.find(d => d.type === "decimal").value}]`);
        this._numeral = new RegExp(`[${numerals.join("")}]`, "g");
        this._index = d => index.get(d);
    }
    parse(string) {
        return (string = string.trim()
            .replace(this._minusSign, "-")
            .replace(this._group, "")
            .replace(this._decimal, ".")
            .replace(this._numeral, this._index)) ? +string : NaN;
    }
}

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('sv-se', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});

const value = -2;
const parser = new NumberParser('sv-se');
console.log(formatter.format(value));               // −2,00 (U+2212)
console.log(parser.parse(formatter.format(value))); // -2 (U+002D)
console.log(parser.parse(formatter.format(value)) === value); // true
```