# Does Javascript have a way to parse numeric strings accounting for different global character sets?

Tags: javascript, unicode, internationalization, unicode-string

Is there a way to validate/parse strings into integers when the characters used may use numeral character sets other than the standard Western 0-9?

Background: My Javascript application prompts users for integer input (their age), but some users answer using non-Western numerals due to their keyboard settings. Currently, those don't pass validation, but I'd like to accept and parse all valid integer responses, regardless of what numeral character set is used.

Desired behavior:

```
"12" => 12 // English/Western
"১৬" => 16 // Assamese
"२४" => 24 // Hindi
```

Is there a way to do this consistently without hardcoding all possible numeral sets explicitly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any JavaScript standard API to parse to number according to locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364947/is-there-any-javascript-standard-api-to-parse-to-number-according-to-locale)

Comment: @Yogi -- it comes close. The custom implementation (second part of the accepted answer) creates a parser for a specific alternate numeral encoding. This works if I can anticipate what character set the end user has, but doesn't work well in a truly globalized setting where users have a wide variety of numeral character locales.